# How can I show a product that is out of stock in a configured product

Tags: configurable-product, out-of-stock, magento-2.2.1

When a product is out of stock (and this is set up), it disappears from the configured product and its drop-down menu.

How can I make it continue to be shown there (as an option of the general product) and when someone selects it then the out-of-stock label to be shown.

Comment: Go to admin > Stores > configuration > Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options Set Display "Out of Stock Products" to YES